# how to destructure a map as key and value

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to destructure a key value pair ? I have a function which take a map as a parameter, I would like to extract the value of both the key and the value in the params itself. How do I do that ?

I can do the following with a vector -

> ((fn [[a b]] (str a b)) [a b])

How do I do the same / similar with map -

> ((fn[{k v}] (str k v)) {k v})

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: I don't know what Ankur is talking about, but try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505603/how-to-destructure-a-map-as-key-and-value/12505893#12505893

Answer (score 19):

map destructuring in functions arg lists is designed for extracting certain keys from a map and giving them names like so:

```
core> (defn foo [{my-a :a my-b :b}] {my-a my-b})
core/foo                                                                                     
core> (foo {:a 1 :b 2})
{1 2}
```

i recommend [this tutorial](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html). It is a little hard to give a direct equivalent to `((fn[{k v}] (str k v)) {k v})` because the map could have many keys and many values so the destructuring code would be unable to tell which key and value you where looking for. Destructuring by key is easier to reason about.

If you want to arbitrarily choose the first entry in the map you can extract it and use the list destructuring form on a single map entry:

```
core> (defn foo [[k v]] {v k})
#'core/foo                                                                                     
core> (foo (first {1 2}))
{2 1}
```

in this example the list destructuring form `[k v]` is used because first returns the first map entry as a vector.

Comment: It is also idiomatic and convenient to auto-assign map values to symbols corresponding to key names. This is written like this: `(defn foo [{:keys [a b]}] (str a b))`. Then at the function call: `(foo {:a 1 :b 2})`. This will return `"12"`.

Comment: The second example is really useful when processing all the key/value pairs in a map, since the seq view of a map is a list of key/value pairs. E.g. (map (fn [[k v]] (println k v)) my-map)

Answer (score 2):

There are shortcuts available for destructuring maps. For example, if you're looking for specific keys, then you don't have to type out name1 :key1 name1 :key2...

e.g.

```
main=> (defn fbb [{:keys [foo bar baz]}] (+ foo bar baz))
#'main/fbb
main=> (fbb {:foo 2 :bar 3 :baz 4}) 
9
```

instead of...

```
(defn fbb [{foo :foo bar :bar baz :baz}] (+ foo bar baz))
```

If your map keys are strings, you can say `:strs` instead of `:keys` and if they are symbols you can use `:syms`.

Answer (score -3):

```
user=> (for [x (hash-map :a 1 :b 2 :c 3)] (str (first x) " " (second x)))
(":a 1" ":c 3" ":b 2")
```

Comment: The question is about `de-structure a map` not about `concat first 2 elements of a set`

Comment: His above example worked with my code... Can you show me that it doesn't?

Comment: The sample code is just an example of a map with 1 key value pair, what about the passed map has 5 key/value pairs, how does your code handle that? Ex: map {:name "superman" :age 1000 :job "superhero"}, now we need to destructure all the three keys and their value... NOTE: destructure not extract manually

Comment: He didn't say that was his issue. His example is a simple {a b}. Coding is about problem solving :P

Comment: Coding is for sure about problem solving but the first step starts with understanding the problem :)

Comment: Touche. Thanks for the challenge.